# How to split city, state, country string using postgresql

Tags: arrays, postgresql, split

I need to split "Indianapolis, Indiana, United States" into "Indianapolis" in one column and "Indiana, United States" in another.

However `users_geo.location_name` has examples such as:

- "Kane, Illinois, United States"
- "New Jersey, United States"
- "Washington, D.C., United States"

Where the city doesn't always exist in the first position. Ideally, I would like to filter for strings with atleast 3 words, then take the first word and put it into a new column.

I have tried:

```sql
SELECT location_name, 
       regexp_split_to_table(users_geo.location_name, E',') AS city
FROM public.users_geo;
```

However it turns out like the screenshot which causes duplication.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFiXq.png)

Comment: What's the range of locations you need to process: USA-islands and territories, all of USA, USA+Canada, or is it more? How clean is your data: do you expect typos, varying punctuation and capitalisation, locations outside your target area? Do you need this to stay up to date (moving boundaries, changing names)? For a quick and dirty approach, you can look up and adjust one of [existing regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=city+state+country+regex) but there are also publicly available, curated lists/databases like National Address Database, that you could match against.